# How can I use Linq for this?

Tags: c#, linq

Imagine I have the following arrays:

```
int[] player = new int[5] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 4 };
int[] computer = new int[5] { 1, 1, 1, 3, 5 };
```

How can I use a Linq query to fetch the amount of times each number is in each collection?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var count =
    from i in player
    group i by i into g
    select new { Number = g.Key, Count = g.Count() }
```

Answer (score 3):

This would give you the frequency of each number in the `player` array, same would work for the `computer` array:

```
var playerFrequencies = player.GroupBy(n => n)
                              .Select(g => new { Number = g.Key, 
                                                Frequency = g.Count() })
                              .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  int HowManyTimes(IEnumerable<int> numberCollection, int numberToFind){
        return numberCollection.Count(x = >x == numberToFind);
  }
```